# Laravel 5.6 getRouteKeyName() not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

This is the code I have so far:

Web.php

```
Route::get('/{uri}', 'PageController@show')->name('page.show');
```

PageController

```
// Show the requested page
public function show(Page $page)
{
    return view('templates.page', compact('page'));
}
```

Page model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'uri';
}
```

My question is how come the Route-model-binding is not working and not finding the page in the controller even though I have changed the route key name. It just has an empty model in the controller and has not found the page.

Comment: You misunderstood the whole thing, read the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding). The route param name must match with the type hinted variable name. The `getRouteKeyName ` helps customizing to query in the `db` using that key other than `id`.

Comment: That makes sense I changed the line of code in web.php to:

Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@show')->name('page.show');

This now works, Thank you.

Is this best practice though?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should do something like the following:

```php
// Route
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@show')->name('page.show');

// Controller Method
public function show(Page $page)
{
    return view('templates.page', compact('page'));
}
```

If `/{page}` contains an `id` like: `1` and your pages table has `id` column then all done but if you would like to query the pages table other than an id then declare the `getRouteKeyName` method in your `Page` model and retuen that column name from that method. So for example, if your pages table has unique `slug` and your `uri` has something like `example.com/contact` then declare the following method:

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug'; // db column name
}
```

Now, the framework will query for a page using something like `where slug = {slug from uri}` other than `id`/default. Hope it helps now.