# Laravel routes don't work with slugs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

route() function doesn't generate url with slug

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/tasks/{task}', 'TasksController@show')->name('task.show');
```

Tasks model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Tasks Controller

```
public function show(Tasks $task){
    $task_full = Tasks::with('tags')->find($task->id);
    return view('tasks.show', ['task'=>$task_full]);
}
```

Finally route() function in my view that works the way I didn't expect. It generates url like this - laravel.test/tasks/3. 
And I want it to use slugs.

```
<a href="{{route('task.show', ['task'=>$task])}}"><li>{{$task->body}}</li></a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233800/laravel-5-6-getroutekeyname-not-working/50234079#50234079

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that you use the slug as id in the route function :

```
{{route('task.show', $task->slug)}}
```

Comment: I use model binding feature, so that I have to pass Model, not slug or id.

Comment: I found my mistake... I simply edit route() method in a wrong view. Yikes!