# Laravel 5.8 - Fetching models using getRouteKeyName() slug not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

For reference I used this post and Laravel documentation:

[Laravel 5.6 getRouteKeyName() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233800/laravel-5-6-getroutekeyname-not-working)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding

In my routes I have a resources array like this:

```
Route::resources([
    ...
    'state' => 'StateController',
    ...
]);
```

In my controller I am trying to access models by the slug. My state table and model has name and slug columns.

`StateController`

```
public function show(State $state)
{
    dd($state);
    // return view('state.show', compact('state'));
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

If I remove the `State` model typecast it prints out the  string `indiana` for the url: `http://codebase.localhost.com/state/indiana` But when I put the typecast back in, it gives me a 404. It can't find the model.

I thought `getRouteKeyName` was supposed to retrieve the model by the string passed.

What gives?

Here are my models `fillables`

```
'name', 'order', 'slug'
```

It's definitely a record in my table.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the `getRouteKeyName` supposed to be in the model (not the controller as shown above) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the `getRouteKeyName` method being defined in your controller.
From the docs:

> you may override the getRouteKeyName method on the Eloquent model

Try moving the `getRouteKeyName` method into your `State` model.

Comment: I completely missed that. Thank you so much <3